# Where is the Joomla! SQL stored?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I am trying to get the SQL to display all Articles from a Category.

This is my closest match, but some articles still appear not in the correct order:

```
SELECT title
FROM j2suq_content
WHERE catid = 18
AND state = 1
AND NOW() >= publish_up 
AND (NOW() <= publish_down or publish_down < publish_up)
ORDER BY id 
DESC;
```

So, I am wondering how Joomla! gets all articles from a category? There seem to be no views in the database.

Best regards

Comment: Your query seems correct. What is your result and what do you expect.

Comment: I have a joomla module which shows articles from a category. I want to recreate the output from this module. So I tried to select my articles by category and order them by the publish_up column. This was my first try, secondly I tried the query above. But still some articles are out of order. I guess this is because some articles have the exact same publish_up timestamp. But it is shown correctly via the joomla module. I expect the output from the query above just like the output from the joomla module.

Comment: is this a built in joomla module? Try turning on debug to see the exact query. You can see the order by clause there?